# Unable to decrypt data in python Encrypted data from Angular

Tags: python, angular9, cryptojs

Angular Encryption:

```
encrypt(data){
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('824601be6c2941fabe7fe256d4d5a2b7');
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('1011121314151617'); 
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), key, { iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC });
encrypted =encrypted.toString();
encrypted = (iv+encrypted).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
return encrypted
}
```

Decryption From Python:

```
COMMON_ENCRYPTION_KEY=b'824601be6c2941fabe7fe256d4d5a2b7'
COMMON_16_BYTE_IV_FOR_AES=b'1011121314151617'

def decrypt_with_common_cipher(self, ciphertext):
    raw_ciphertext = base64.b64decode(ciphertext)
    print("raw_ciphertext", raw_ciphertext)
    
    try:
        AES.new(self.COMMON_ENCRYPTION_KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, self.COMMON_16_BYTE_IV_FOR_AES).decrypt(raw_ciphertext)[:16]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Angular Encryption working fine I am getting the encrypted value example : 1011121314151617HsV4+WIGfm1VSRFZbFqSPo5ZKDjDgS36/L8JTDyYH0rkDigS7lSXaQfgCWrKlw9MzKqlJ66eQWSVNwWAotGyZg==. But when I try from Python to decrypt using same key and IV. am getting Error as: Data must be padded to 16 byte boundary in CBC mode